# ¿como solucionar incompatibilidad de versiones en python entre dos librerías de mi proyecto?

Tags: python, web

Estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación web y me da problemas y no tengo muy claro como solucionarlo.
Estoy usando streamlit para hacerla. Todo el proyecto está hecho con python.

En contexto, primero creé una aplicación que se usa para optimizar turnos de trabajo. Para ello usé ortools. Esta aplicación lee un par de csv y devuelve otro csv con los turnos de trabajo.

La función principal que al ejecutarse coge la info y devuelve el resultado se llama solve_shift_scheduling.

Lo que he hecho es ponerle un return a mi función solve_shift_scheduling con un dataframe que guarda lo que originalmente era un csv.

Luego en mi app.py hago esto:

```
import pandas as pd
from shift_scheduling_sat_revCREF_v20 import solve_shift_scheduling

'#ESTADILLOS INTERACTIVOS'

estadillo = solve_shift_scheduling()

st.dataframe(estadillo)
```

Me da este error:

```
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

He estado investigando e intentando cambiar versiones de streamlit y ortools pero no hay una versión disponible de ortools para la versión de protobuf que necesita streamlit y viceversa. O yo no he conseguido ejecutarla. Tampoco tengo muy claro que haya hecho la llamada a mi función bien o que no haya entendido que me pide el error.

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383927/1545868) de referencia, desinstala el paquete actual y luego instala el paquete compatible. Según el mensaje de error, requiere la versión 3.20.*

```
> python -m pip uninstall protobuf
> python -m pip install protobuf==3.20.*
```